Receiving Gattcallbackerror:22 .NET MAUI app
I am trying to connect and send data from one device to another connected device using a .NET MAUI app and Plugin.BLE.
showData.xaml.cs
using InTheHand.Bluetooth;
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Exceptions;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace sample;

public partial class ShowData : ContentPage
{ 
    private List<IDevice> deviceList = new List<IDevice>();
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public ShowData(string cityLbl, string description, int pressure, int humidity, string countryName, int time_zone, bool clouds)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        city.Text = "City : " + cityLbl;
        desp.Text = "Weather Description : " + description;
        pres.Text = "Pressure : " + pressure.ToString();
        hum.Text = "Humidity : " + humidity.ToString();
        country.Text = "Country : " + countryName.ToString();
        time.Text = "Time : " + time_zone.ToString();

        clouds_data.Text = "Clouds : " + clouds.ToString();    
    }

    private async void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var adapter =  CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
       if(adapter != null)
        {
            var systemDevices = adapter.GetSystemConnectedOrPairedDevices();

            var filteredDevices = systemDevices.Where(device => device.Name != null).ToList();

            ScanFilterOptions filterOptions = new ScanFilterOptions();

            var deviceList = filteredDevices.Select(device => device.Name);

            if (systemDevices.Count > 0 && systemDevices != null)
            {
                string deviceNames = string.Join(", ", deviceList.Select(device => device));
                await DisplayAlert("Devices", $"{systemDevices}", "Ok");
                await DisplayAlert("SystemDevices", $"{systemDevices[0]}", "Ok");

                var device = systemDevices[0];
                var guid = device.Id;

                try
                {
                    if (device.IsConnectable)
                    {
                        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);

                        try
                        {
                            await adapter.ConnectToKnownDeviceAsync(guid);
                        }
                        catch(DeviceConnectionException ex) {
                            await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
                        }

                        var services = await device.GetServicesAsync(cancellationToken);

                        foreach (var service in services)
                        {
                            var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattDescriptorUuids.ValidRange);

                            string msg = "Hello";
                            byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

                            await characteristic.WriteAsync(msgBuffer);
                            await DisplayAlert("Sent", "Message sent successfully!", "Ok");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Device is not connectable!", "Ok");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Devices", "No Bluetooth devices found", "Ok");
            }
        }
       else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Devices", "Null adapter", "Ok");
        }
    }    
}

The device is getting connected but immediately after connecting the app is giving GattCallBack Error : 22 in the exception alert!
After adding breakpoints I got to know that it is happening after the following line -
'await adapter.ConnectToKnownDeviceAsync(guid);'
I have provided all the necessary permission in the manifest.xaml file
however I am not able to connect the devices and send data.
Help appreciated!

Error 22 usually means that the device is not paired, is the device already paired?

@FreakyAli I paired the device this time, now it is giving GattCallback error : 4
Help!

Check this class it will tell you which error means what https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/ea7ab70a711e642653dd5922b83aa04a53af9e0e/stack/include/gatt_api.h

Which line reports such a problem? And could you please post the full log of this problem?

@JessieZhang-MSFT the following line is giving the error
await adapter.ConnectToKnownDeviceAsync(guid);
and the error message is only the gattcallbackerror

From the document Connect to known Device, we could find that On Android this will throw a GATT ERROR in a couple of seconds if the device is out of range.

@JessieZhang-MSFT actually the device is not out of range , when I try to manually connect that device then it happens perfectly.

How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

@JessieZhang-MSFT  AS soon as the testing device gets connected with another device using bluetooth , it provides this exception and disconnects instantly. Both the physical devices are in close proximity of each other, then how can they get disconnected?
